# What is the best practice for passing arguments to event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

Consider the following block of HTML:

```
<button id="follow-user1" class="btnFollow">Follow User1</button>
<button id="follow-user2" class="btnFollow">Follow User2</button>
<button id="follow-user3" class="btnFollow">Follow User3</button>
<button id="follow-user4" class="btnFollow">Follow User4</button>
```

There are several ways I could bind an event handler to each of the buttons:

### Through `onclick="code()"` (Bad Practice):

```
<button id="follow-user1" class="btnFollow" onclick="alert(1)">Follow User1</button>
```

```html
<button id="follow-user1" class="btnFollow" onclick="alert(1)">Follow User1</button>
<button id="follow-user2" class="btnFollow" onclick="alert(1)">Follow User2</button>
<button id="follow-user3" class="btnFollow" onclick="alert(1)">Follow User3</button>
<button id="follow-user4" class="btnFollow" onclick="alert(1)">Follow User4</button>
```

### Through the `id` of the element:

```
$("#follow-user1").click(function(){
 alert(1);
});
```

```js
$("#follow-user1").click(function(){
  alert(1);
});
$("#follow-user2").click(function(){
  alert(2);
});
$("#follow-user3").click(function(){
  alert(3);
});
$("#follow-user4").click(function(){
  alert(4);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="follow-user1" class="btnFollow">Follow User1</button>
<button id="follow-user2" class="btnFollow">Follow User2</button>
<button id="follow-user3" class="btnFollow">Follow User3</button>
<button id="follow-user4" class="btnFollow">Follow User4</button>
```

### Through the `class` of the element, using the `:eq()` selector:

```
$(".btnFollow:eq(0)").click(function(){
 alert(1);
});
```

```js
$(".btnFollow:eq(0)").click(function() {
  alert(1);
});
$(".btnFollow:eq(1)").click(function() {
  alert(2);
});
$(".btnFollow:eq(2)").click(function() {
  alert(3);
});
$(".btnFollow:eq(3)").click(function() {
  alert(4);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="follow-user1" class="btnFollow">Follow User1</button>
<button id="follow-user2" class="btnFollow">Follow User2</button>
<button id="follow-user3" class="btnFollow">Follow User3</button>
<button id="follow-user4" class="btnFollow">Follow User4</button>
```

Which of these is best practice? Is there a better / easier way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Attach events to all the buttons ? What about this `$(".btnFollow").click(function() {
  alert(1);
});`

Comment: Assuming the event handlers are almost the same, then none of the above is ideal.  Use a single common event handler that just examines which button was clicked to modify its behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `data-` attribute.

If you want to catch specific clicks, you can subscribe to different data attributes:

```
$('*[data-subscribe-to="mynumber"]');
```

And if you want to use the data from the clicked element, you can use:

```
$(element).data('subscribe-to');
```

Comment: That seems to be a good way of going about it. I'll accept that as the answer.